# How to make java.util.Date thread-safe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

As far as i know that `java.util.Date` is mutable, so it's not thread-safe if multiple threads tried to accessing and modifying it. How do we use client-side locking or composition (wrapper) to make it thread-safe ?

Comment: If we are already here, `GregorianCalendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` aren't thread-safe as well. Always worth to remind.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In this order, from best to worst:

0. Not use it at all, check out Java 8's [new Date and Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).
1. Not use it at all, check out [jodatime](/questions/tagged/jodatime)
2. Not use it at all, use `AtomicLong` or immutable primitive `long` with `volatile` to represent *epoch time*
3. Encapsulate it. Always return defensive copy of `Date`, never a reference to internal object
4. Synchronize on `Date` instance.

Comment: I am wondering why did you consider the 2nd is better than the 3rd ?

Comment: @user1389813: Good question! 1. Primitives are immutable and thus implicitly thread-safe. 2. You cannot, by coincidence, return reference to internal object rather than a defensive copy. 3. More lightweight, less copying (not really a big deal). However I agree, 2 and 3 are both pretty good. Also obviously `Date` has better semantics than `long`.

Comment: I see. The 2nd point you need the guard it with a lock right ? as @dystroy pointed it out the increment operation is not atomic.

Comment: @user1389813: yes, that's why it's better to use `AtomicLong` (I'll actually put it on the first place) which allows atomic updates without locking (CAS instr.)

Comment: Now that [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) is approved, I suggest the first option to be **not use it at all, check out [Java 8's new Date and Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).**

Answer (score 4):

You may use the long value (milliseconds since Epoch) instead of a Date instance. Assigning it will be an atomic operation and it would always be coherent.

But your problem maybe isn't on the Date value itself but on the whole algorithm, meaning the real answer would be based on your real problem.

Here's a example of buggy operation in a multithread context :

```
long time;
void add(long duration) {
   time += duration; 
}
```

The problem here is that you may have two additions in parallel resulting in only one effective addition, because `time += duration` isn't atomic (it's really `time=time+duration`).

Using a long instead of a mutable object isn't enough. In this case you could solve the problem by setting the function as synchronized but other cases could be more tricky.

Comment: What do you mean by 'your problem maybe isn't on the data value itself but on the whole algorithm

Comment: If you're doing a long operation starting by reading the date and finishing by replacing the value. Locking the value during the operation might do it.

Comment: will it help if making it to volatile ?

Comment: I see the problem now, so which means both AtomicLong and volatile can't address the problem. You still need to lock it ?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to never modify a Date and never share it. i.e. Only use Date for local variables.

You can use JodaTime as it has immutable date objects.

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple solution to create a thread-safe wrapper of `Date` class. The best way is to synchronize all usages of it's objects by using `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: Then you need to carry that synchronize block whereever you use it. Isn't it not good in practice ?

Comment: It's awful in code. This is why Tomasz answer is much better than mine ;)