# Efficient Data Transfer mechanism

Tags: java, performance, file-io, data-transfer

I am developing a Java class to transfer data from any input stream to any output stream (mainly to be used on-line, but with a broader range of utilities).

After wandering through the Java 7 API specification I noticed two methods from the `FileChannel` class: `transferFrom(...)` and `transferTo`.

I developed my class around these methods and created the following `transmit()` method:

```
public void transmit() throws IOException {
    File tmp = File.createTempFile("transmit", ".tmp");
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(tmp, "rw");
    FileChannel fc = raf.getChannel();
    fc.force(true);
    fc.transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(src), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    raf.seek(0);
    fc.transferTo(0, Long.MAX_VALUE, Channels.newChannel(dst));
    raf.close();
}
```

And then I decided to test it out a bit with the following test (the first version did not use a temporary byte array and as expected did worse than the `transmit()` method):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File from = File.createTempFile("source", ".tmp");
    File to = File.createTempFile("destination", ".tmp");

    FileOutputStream tmp = new FileOutputStream(from);

    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 20); i++) {
        tmp.write(0);
    }

    tmp.close();

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(from);
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(to);

    DataTransmitter dt = new DataTransmitter(fin, fout);

    long time_1 = new Date().getTime();
    dt.transmit();
    time_1 = new Date().getTime() - time_1;

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    to.delete();

    fin = new FileInputStream(from);
    fout = new FileOutputStream(to);


    int len;
    byte[] b = new byte[8192];
    long time_2 = new Date().getTime();
    while ((len = fin.read(b)) >= 0) {
        fout.write(b, 0, len);
    }
    time_2 = new Date().getTime() - time_2;

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    System.out.format("Transmitter method: %s milliseconds%n", time_1);
    System.out.format("Direct method: %s milliseconds%n", time_2);
}
```

On a file located in the local hard drive the so called "direct method" was quite faster (192 milliseconds for the `transmit()` method and 8 milliseconds for the "direct method") meaning the "direct method" was highly efficient compared to the `transmit()` method.

However, since the purpose of this class is to download files from an on-line source I created a 40 Mb file that I uploaded to a personal cloud and (from a method similar to the above) got the following results:

```
Transmitter method: 126478 milliseconds
Direct method (8192 bytes): 134105 milliseconds
```

Which means the `transmit()` method was more efficient coming from an on-line source.

I was wondering if these results are accurate (since these methods are system dependent I state that I'm running Ubuntu 13.10) and if they are, how can I find a way to optimize the `transmit()` method to a general situation.

If there are alternative methods that are more efficient I would also appreciate if someone stated them (no code is required, just an explanation of the method and maybe the reason why it is more efficient).

Comment: This sort of open-ended "any suggestions?" question is probably more suitable for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't write your own data transfer code, unless you have a very specific reason to do so. There are many data transfer java libraries: [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html), some parts of [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/), etc. You should not reinvent the wheel, unless you want to do it for a school project or you see a weakness in the existing solutions which you want to improve on.

Also, speaking of bad practices, you shouldn't be using java's Date, but rather a more sane Date functionality, like [Joda's DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) and you shouldn't be opening/closing your own streams but either use a library that does it for you or use Java 7's [Closable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) and [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

**EDIT:**
Another bad practice you do in your example is that you use java.util.Date to obtain the current time. This is wrong on two levels: code readability and thread safety.

For the code readability part: what you are trying to do is `'give me the current time'`, which you can clearly do by `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`. What you are actually doing is:

> 'allocate a semi-deprecated object, don't specify timezone or locale
> (which might change from the first call to the second call), don't be
> thread-safe, and give me its current time so I can use it as my
> current time'

. Creating two extra objects when you can easily avoid it is not a big deal, but since a method for giving you the current time exists, and it is more efficient, you should use it, otherwise you are developing bad practices.

For the thread safety part, you can read this:
[How to make Java.util.Date thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252967/how-to-make-java-util-date-thread-safe)

Just code using java.util.Date is inherently prone to errors and you shouldn't be using it. It might not seem like a big deal in this example, but details are important if you are developing yourself as a software engineer. In addition, you shouldn't be writing your own methods for data transfer unless you know what is wrong with the existing ones and you want to improve on that or you are doing it for the purpose of a homework or study.

Comment: How is `Date` at all unsuitable for the OP's use case? Either way, Joda Time is a replacement for what `java.util.Calendar` does, rather than what `Date` is supposed to be. (Mostly a strongly typed wrapper around a `long`.)

Comment: @millimoose all code using Date is inherently clumsy and wrong. In addition, in this example, the OP is using Date as a freaky way of obtaining System.getCurrentTimeMillis() and allocates additional objects, which is a bad practice, in addition to not being readable. If you want to get the current time, get the current time, don't create an obscure deprecated object and take it out of it. In addition, his code using Date is not threadsafe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252967/how-to-make-java-util-date-thread-safe.

Comment: They're not using threads, sharing the `Date`s, or mutating them. Thread safety is a straw man you're building – you probably use mutable (as ORMs require) entity classes all over the place without saying they're "inherently error-prone". "Not readable" subjective, I'd say it's a wash between `new Date()` or `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`. Allocating additional objects being bad practice is simply ludicrous, in any Java program that's not very specifically coded to avoid this you're going to be allocating all sorts of random very short-lived garbage.

Comment: And `Date` itself isn't deprecated - it's calendar calculation functionality is. I.e. the methods that convert between an abstract timestamp, and a human-readable date and time. They were deprecated because they didn't really support internationalisation or time-zones – the API seems to have only supported the current system locale and TZ, and instead of fixing that in the `Date` class, the JDK adopted the ICU's `Calendar` component. (For better or worse. It's `Calendar`'s API being insane that's an important motivation behind Joda Time.)

Comment: @millimoose, almost all of the Date functionality is deprecated, apart from a constructor. Comeon, don't be ridiculous. Code having Date can't be production code. And the suggested method with the "see" annotation on Date's getTime() method is exactly System.getCurrentTimeMillis(). It is what the OP should be using to get the time. Period.

Comment: I'm not being ridiculous. I just know the complete story, and the emphasis should be on "**almost**". There are reasons why *exactly those* methods that are deprecated became that way, and the constructor didn't. You have exactly no facts to support your interpretation of the deprecations, you just happen to like Joda Time a lot. Which is fine, it's a good library. It's just not necessary in the OP's case, and `new Date()` vs `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()` is a complete and utter wash. There's no practical reason to use one over the other when measuring wall clock time like this.

Comment: Just from readability perspective: System.currentTimeMillis() means 'give me the current time', while new Date().getTime() reads: 'instantiate a date object, and retrieve its time'. Also, if you happen to read the documentation of the getTime() method, you'd see that wiser than you and me developers have pointed you in the direction of the right method to use, which is System.getCurrentTimeMillis(). By the way, I don't think that stubbornness and not willing to improve upon one's code doesn't take one very far in software engineering.